# RxJava: How to interrupt thread on unsubscribe?

Tags: rx-java, cancellation

I use `Observable.create()` to create an observable to perform some work on a scheduler (e.g. `Schedulers.io()` and then return a result on `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`.

```
val subscription = observable<T> {
        try {
            // perform action synchronously
            it.onNext(action.invoke(context, args))
            it.onCompleted()
        } catch (t: Exception) {
            it.onError(t)
        }
    }.subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    {
                        // handle result here
                        result.set(it)
                    },
                    {
                        // handle error here
                        errorHandler.handleTaskError(model, this, it)
                    },
                    {
                        // notify completed
                        model.completeTask(this)
                    }
            )
```

The operation inside `action.invoke()` is synchronous and might be a blocking IO operation. When user decides to cancel it, I unsubscribe from the observable: `subscription.unsubscribe()`

However, the I/O operation is not being interrupted. Is there any rx-java API to interrupt the operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `yourSubscription.unsubscribe();`, Rx will call your unsubscribe code.

This unsuscribe code will be the `Subscription` class that you can `add` to your `subscriber` when you create your `Observable`.

```
Observable<Object> obs = Observable.create(subscriber -> {

      subscriber.add(new Subscription() {
            @Override
            public void unsubscribe() {
                 // perform unsubscription
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isUnsubscribed() {
                return false;
            }
        });
      subscriber.onNext(/**...*/);
      subscriber.onCompleted();
}
```

So in the `unsubscribe` method, you can interrupt your job, if you have a way to do so.

Please note that the unsubscribe method is called when you unsubscribe from an Observable or when An Observable when it's completed. (it will unsubscribe by itself)

**edit** : taking [vladimir mironov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1950649/vladimir-mironov) comment in account

Comment: Please note, that `subscriber.add` must be called before `subscriber.onNext` and `subscriber.onCompleted` methods

Answer (score 3):

RxJava schedulers use Furure.cancel(true) to interrupt a running action so if you have an interrupt sensitive operation (such as `Thread.sleep()`), you should see the thread interruption, although you can't do much about it because at that point, the entire downstream chain has been unsubscribed and no further events are can reach your subscriber.

If your action is not sensitive to interruption and it doesn't provide any standard means to interrupt it (such as calling `close()` on a socket, or `cancel()` on a JDBC statement), RxJava can't do much about it.

If you can call some close() method asynchronously, consider using `using()` which let's you specify a cleanup callback that can close your resource on unsubscription.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's impossible with RxJava.

You can keep reference to the `action` object outside of the observable and interrupt it along with `unsubscribe` call.